# Undefined reference when parsing a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm really new to the matter so please bear with me on this one. I have to parse a json file that is structured this way:

```
    {"elements": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "my name",
            "description": "my description",
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "my name 2",
            "description": "my description 2",
        },
```

and I'm doing this as follows, using xmlhttprequest and JSON.parse:

```
//      asynchronous call to open the cards json
        request.open("GET", "../json/stuff.json", true);

//      send request to web server
        request.send();

//      onreadystatechange fires when the request state changes
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
//            if the readystate is 4 the response from web server is ready
//            if the request status is 200 the status is ok
              if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
                 stuff = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                 console.log("here");
              }
        }

        console.log(stuff[0]);
```

the "request" variable, just like "stuff", is defined at global scope as follows:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

The problem I get is that "stuff" is undefined, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Welcome to the world of async coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using sync code in async code. The `request.onreadystatechange` is callback, therefore the `console.log` is called before the `request.onreadystatechange`. So:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if the request status is 200 the status is ok
          if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
             stuff = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
             console.log(stuff[0]);
          }
    }
```